# Vuetify 3: How to show avatar at right side of v-select item

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

How can I show an avatar at the right side of an v-select item?

I thought this would work: [Vuetifyjs Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Here is code from playground:

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-select label="Select" :items="items" item-title="title" item-value="title">
        <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
          <template v-slot:append>
            <v-avatar :image="item.avatar"></v-avatar>
          </template>
        </template>
      </v-select>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const items = ref([
  { title: "California", avatar: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/docs/images/logos/vuetify-logo-v3-slim-text-light.svg" },
  { title: "Colorado", avatar: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/docs/images/logos/vuetify-logo-v3-slim-text-light.svg" },
  { title: "Florida", avatar: "https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/docs/images/logos/vuetify-logo-v3-slim-text-light.svg" },
])

</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are a bit hit and miss with version 3 at the moment but for good practice, I would use the list item element for your customisation and bind your props. You probably also want to use the selection slot for improved UI/UX.

```
  <v-select label="Select" :items="items" item-title="title" item-value="title">
    <template v-slot:selection="{ item, index, props }">               
      <v-list-item :append-avatar="item.raw.avatar" v-bind="props">{{item.raw.title}}</v-list-item> 
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item="{ item, props }">
      <v-list-item :append-avatar="item.raw.avatar" v-bind="props"></v-list-item>
    </template>
  </v-select>
```

Example: [Vuetify Play](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#slots

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using a slot within a slot (`append` nested inside `item`).  v-select supports either or, not both nested together.  For your use case you can just use `item` slot

```html
<template #item="{ item }">
  <div>
    {{ item.title }}
    <v-avatar :image="item.raw.avatar" />
  </div>
</template>
```

[updated playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)